# SQL: Single select query from 2 Non-Joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables which doesn't have any references to each other and I'm trying to create a third table (for reference lookup) by selecting from fields from both tables.

```
TableA has an A_ID
TableB has a B_ID
```

I want to create Table C which has a 1 to 1 reference between A_ID to B_ID
where A_ID = FirstID and B_ID = SecondID, I can't join the 2 tables because there's nothing in common.

Something like:

```
Insert INTO [TableC]
(FirstID, SecondID)
SELECT
A_ID As FirstID,
(Select B_ID From TableB)
FROM TableA
```

Basically we are creating a relationship right now with Table C so that we can use it to reference the two tables in the future using the their IDs.

Comment: If you can't join the tables because "there's nothing in common", where will the data come from to fill table C?

Comment: Basically we are creating a relationship right now with Table C so that we can use it to reference the two tables in the future using the their IDs.

Comment: Are you attempting to create a logical relationship between these two tables through a new third table?

Comment: yes. base on our current data structure, we need a relationship between those 2 tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming TableA and TableB truly have nothing in common, then what you want is the Cartesian product, that is, for every row in A times every row in B.

```
INSERT INTO TableC(FirstID,SecondID)
SELECT A_ID,B_ID
FROM TableA
CROSS JOIN TableB
```

Perhaps what you really want is to join them by ROW_NUMBER().

```
INSERT INTO TableC(FirstID,SecondID)
SELECT A_ID,B_ID
FROM (SELECT A_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) as rownumA FROM TableA) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT B_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever) as rownumB FROM TableB) b ON a.rownumA=b.rownumB
```